# launch android app with custom uri

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, intentfilter

I tried to launch my android application with a link into an email.

```
https://hostname.com/somethingAndParameter
```

My server redirect this link to:

```
myscheme://host
```

i tried this intent-filter but it doesn't work:

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:host="host" android:scheme="myscheme"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Looks fine to me, try removing the BROWSABLE category, and also see what happens if you just specify a host OR scheme in the data filter, instead of both. Are you sure the URI looks exactly like you expect?

Comment: i tried to removed the BROWSABLE category, but nothing change my navigator doesn't intercept the link. And i need both host and scheme because i can receive different link which launch different activities. Example myscheme://activity1 launch activity1 and myscheme://activity2 launch activity2. my email link https:hostname.com/somethingandparameter launch my navigator, my server redirect but the redirection doesn't work. Sorry for my english and thanks for you help :D

Comment: Right, I imagine you will need both, but I was thinking you could start with getting one or the other to work, then it would be easier to debug what the issues are. Maybe the redirect isn't getting handled properly? What if you link direct to myscheme://host instead of the redirect?

Comment: Conversely, why not set up your `<intent-filter>` to listen for `https://hostname.com/somethingAndParameter` directly?

Comment: Thanks Matt for your time. I try with: <a href="myscheme://host">Link for email</a> but the result is the same, with scheme alone or both scheme and host. I have a web page unaivalable.

Comment: @CommonsWare because the link is into an email and the same link is used for iphone app, web site and android app. The redirection work in iphone and web site so I try to do work with android. Again sorry for my english.

Comment: "because the link is into an email and the same link is used for iphone app, web site and android app" -- that would be all the more reason to have your app listen for `https://hostname.com/somethingAndParameter` directly.

Comment: @CommonsWare iOS does not know to do. For open an iOS app with link, this link must be custom.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not understanding by way of comments, let's try an answer...

Change your `<intent-filter>` to:

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data
           android:scheme="https"
           android:host="hostname.com"
           android:path="/somethingAndParameter"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Now your `https://hostname.com/somethingAndParameter` URL works on:

- iOS, because you said that you have this working
- Web, because you said that you have this working
- Android, because now when a user taps on this link (in an email or whatever) on most Android devices, the user will get a chooser, allowing the user to choose your application to process the link

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's doesn't owrk because the link is gnerate by the server with host.com/internalandsomeencryptedparameter internal is present for all links. I need to understand why the redirection is not intercept by android.

Comment: @Hugo: "because the link is gnerate by the server" -- Then use `android:pathPrefix` or `android:pathPattern`.

Comment: @CommonsWareThanks for your help, but my https link redirect to myscheme://host link and when I click on my https link android doesn't intercept my myscheme://host link